# XCode 4.4 - 4.4.1 crashes while stepping through code

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode4.4

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion and XCode 4.4, I've been unable to step through code while debugging. 4.4.1 did not fix the problem. Sometimes it'll step 2 or 3 times, but trying one more step inevitably reveals the bug. Using breakpoints seems to work better, but still crashes on occasion. I've tried reinstalling. Crash log is here: http://pastebin.com/XmqJEVuH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boss just told me to there's a Developer Preview of XCode 4.5. To my surprise, it actually works.